# Django queryset exclude empty foreign key set

Tags: django

I have the following models where B has a many-to-one relationship with A:

```
class A(model.Model):

    name = models.IntegerField()

class B(models.Model

    a = models.ForeignKey(A, db_column='a_id')
```

When I use a queryset on A, is there a way to exclude the rows in A that have no rows in B?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [`isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#isnull) :

```
A.objects.filter(b__isnull=False).distinct()
```

Using `distinct()` prevents duplicate entries, otherwise each `a` appears once for every `b` which is linked to it.

Comment: Why don't you need to use `b_set__isnull=False`?

Comment: @alias51 you don’t use `b_set` inside `filter` by default, I don’t have a more detailed reason. You could look at the docs for [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) and [`related_query_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
no_rows_in_b = B.objects.all().select_related('a')
```

will get you all the B's with A's

Then you can cycle through them and output the A's

If you want non-repeats:

```
no_rows_in_b = B.objects.all().distinct('a').select_related('a')
```

Then:

```
for rec in no_rows_in_b:
    print(rec.a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if you want to be more explicit, you could do something like this:

```
A.objects.exclude(b__isnull=True).distinct()
```

using `exclude` instead of `filter` and using the `True` boolean arg.